# Send RTP packet with scapy and see it in a cap

Tags: python, scapy, void, rtp

I have this code to write a RTP packet in a cap:

```
client = "192.168.10.1"
server = "192.168.10.5"
client_port = 5061
server_port = 5060


rtp = { 
        "sequence": 1,
        "timestamp": 1,
        "marker": 1,
        "payload_type": 17
    }

pkt= Ether()/IP(src=client, dst=server)/UDP(sport=client_port, dport=server_port)/RTP(**rtp)

wrpcap("rtp_pkt.pcap",pkt)
```

The problem is that I see the packet as UDP in wireshark and not RTP. I can see it with SIP structures so I don't know where is the problem,

Comment: You probably need to "decode as" because the port you're chosing is pretty random.

Comment: I did this : bind_layers(UDP, RTP, dport=server_port) after pkt, but doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

In short - Wireshark shows you UDP, because there's no SIP/SDP packets. These packets initiate connection session and Wireshark then can follow the stream and decode UDP to RTP. In SIP/SDP you can find main information: From, To, Media type etc. ([RFC 4566 SDP](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4566), [RFC3621 SIP](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3261)). So even if you build ideal RTP packet with scapy, without session initiation Wireshark will always decode it as UDP.

**EDIT:**
By the way, use bind_layers(UDP, RTP, dport=*) in scapy to bind UDP packets with RTP, might help

Answer (score 0):

You can tell Wireshark to decode a port number as a particular protocol by using the [`-d` option](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/ChCustCommandLine.html). e.g to decode the above packet as RTP use:

```
wireshark -d udp.port==5060,rtp rtp_pkt.pcap
```

Though if you're going to create an RTP packet you should try to avoid using well know part numbers such as 5060 (which usually maps to the SIP protocol - which is why Wireshark tries to decode it as such).